# How does Facebook store tags and hashtags on server

Tags: android, android-layout, tags, hashtag

I am trying to build something like facebook does and I am facing a problem in tagging and placing hashtags in edittext. I want to show only name to the user but I want to save the ID to the server too. So when clicked on the tag it should make the intent with that specific tagged user.

The code goes like this.

```
statusEd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                items.clear();
                friendListAdpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                messageSave();
                final String text = s.toString();


                if (text.lastIndexOf("@") > text.lastIndexOf(" ")) {
                    w = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("@"), text.length());

                    w = w.replace("@", "");
                    requestFriendTAg(w);
                    type = "@";
                }
                else if (text.lastIndexOf("#") > text.lastIndexOf(" ")) {
                    w = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("#"), text.length());

                    w = w.replace("#", "");
                    requestHashTag(w);
                    type = "#";
                }else {

                    sendMassageToServer=sendMassageToServer+text.charAt(text.length() - 1);
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, ""+text.charAt(text.length() - 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

I am adding the userId with the name starting with @ but it is messing up the whole working of the code.
If there is any other way to do so please feel free to give me something more.
Thank you.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Cutta/TagView